# How to calculate $ |\Omega_{tot} - 1| $ at inflation time?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, big-bang, cosmological-inflation

Suppose that we live in a universe that has the following properties:

$$ |\Omega_{tot,0} - 1| = 0.001 $$

How can I calculate the value of $$|\Omega_{tot} - 1|$$ at some other time as, for example, the inflation ($t \approx 10^{-33}$s)?

Should I use the Friedmann equation? Maybe some other trick?
What about if I want to say that in my universe the dominant thing around inflation is matter? How can I adapt the method?

Comment: Pretty sure the first Friedmann equation essentially *is* the total density at time, $a$, where $a$ is the scale factor and can be written as a function of $t$. I warn you, however, that these are very finicky equations. If you use them even slightly outside of their intended function, the results can become wonky and untrustworthy

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the Friedmann equation you are referring to is the one at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation .

I am not sure of your notation, but I think what the absolute value you ask about is *the absolute value of $Ω_k$*, the present value of the curvature density of the universe. You probably already know this, but I include it anyway just in case you don't. If $Ω_k=0$, then the universe is flat and infinite. If $Ω_k>0$, then the universe is hyper-hyperbolic and infinite. If $Ω_k<0$, then the universe is hyper-spherical and finite.

I interpret your question as choosing a current ($t=t_0=now$) value for $\Omega_{k,0}$, and asking for a formula for calculating the value of $\Omega_{k,1}$ for the time
$$(Eq\ 1)\ t_1 = 10^{-33} s.$$
The values I am using are very approximate to keep the calculations simple.
The scale factor for $t_0$ is
$$(Eq\ 2)\ a(t_0)=1.$$
The reciprocal of the Hubble parameter for $t_0$ is
$$(Eq\ 3)\ 1/H_0 = 1.4\ 10^{10}yr = 4.4\ 10^{17}s.$$
For convenience, (and my liking of the finite universe), I choose the specific value
$$(Eq\ 4)\ \Omega_{k,0}\ =\ -0.001.$$
Three more $\Omega$ constants needing values are the following.
$$(Eq\ 5)\ \Omega_{R,0}\ =\ 0.0001$$
$$(Eq\ 6)\ \Omega_{M,0}\ =\ 0.3$$
$$(Eq\ 7)\ \Omega_{\Lambda ,0}\ =\ 0.7009 $$
Note that the sum of the four $\Omega$s equals 1.

It will be necessary to find values for several variables: scale factor $a(t_1)$ and its square, Hubble parameter $H_1$ and its square for time $(t_1)$, radius of curvature of universe $R_0$ for time $t_0$, radius of curvature of universe $R_1$ for time $t_1$, and then (finally) $\Omega_{k,1}$.

Equations 9-12 calculates the value for $a^2(t_1)$ based on the assumption that $\Omega_{R,0}/a_1^4$ dominates the four $\Omega$ terms of the Friedmann equation. The value calculated for $a_1$ is
$$(Eq\ 8)\ a_1\ =\ a(t_1)\ =\ 3\ 10^{-9}.$$
The form of the Friedmann equation used is
$$(Eq\ 9)\ H_1^2\ =\ H_0^2\ (\Omega_{R,0} /\ a^4\ +\ \Omega_{M,0} / a^3\ +\ \Omega_{k,0} / a^2\ +\ \Omega_{\Lambda ,0})$$
The values of the four terms involving $\Omega$s are the following.
$$\Omega_{R,0} /\ a^4\ ~=\ 1.2\ 10^{30}$$
$$\Omega_{M,0} /\ a^3\ ~=\ 10^{25}$$
$$\Omega_{k,0} /\ a^2\ ~=\ 1.1\ 10^{14}$$
$$\Omega_{\Lambda,0} /\ a^2\ =\ 0.7009$$
$$(Eq\ 10)\ H = (da/dt)/a\ =\ H_0\ \sqrt {\Omega_{R,0}}\ /\ a^2$$
Solving for dt yields
$$(Eq\ 11)\ dt\ =\ (a\ da\ /\ (H _0\ \sqrt {\Omega_{R,0}}).$$
Integrating and solving for $a^2$ yields the following.
$$(Eq\ 12)\ a^2(t_1)\ =\ 2\ t_1\ H_0\ \sqrt {\Omega_{R,0}}\ ~=\ 9\ 10^{-18}$$
The following the equation relates $\Omega_{k,1}$ to $\Omega_{k,0}$.
$$(Eq\ 13)\ \Omega_{k,1}/\Omega_{k,0} = a_1^2/\Omega_{R,0}$$
Therefore,
$$(Eq\ 14)\ \Omega_{k,1}\ =\ -0.001 * 9\ 10^{-18}\ /\ 0.0001\ =  -9\ 10^{-17}.$$
I am not sure this value presents any intuitive sense of significance. I have added some additional calculations that I think provides some intuitive clarity.

Let $R_0$ and $R_1$ be the radius of curvature of the universe corresponding to Eq 4 and Eq 14 respective. I first calculate $H_1$ based on Eq 10. I then calculate $R_0$ and $R_1$.
$$(Eq\ 15)\ H_1 = H_0\ \sqrt {\Omega_{R,0}}\ /\ a_1^2$$
$$(Eq\ 16)\ R_0\ =\ (c/H_0)/\sqrt {-\Omega_{k,0}}\ =\ 440\ Gly$$
$$(Eq\ 17)\ R_1\ =\ R_0\ a_1 =\ 1300\ ly$$

Comment: Hey! For $\Omega_{tot,0}$ I meant the (total) density parameter as $\Omega_{tot,0} = \sum \Omega_{i,0}$. The problem I'm trying to solve is related to the flatness problem. I saw what you wrote and I'll try to solve it using your idea! Sadly I think that I do not have access to your CosmoCalc. But thanks anyway!

Comment: I am surprised that the CosmoCalc does not work for you. What happens when you try to invoke it?

Comment: It shows a message saying that: "Forbidden! You don't have permission to access this resource." Are you accessing it normally?

Comment: As far as I know I am using it in a normal way.  I have not done any king of logging in.

Comment: I have just tried to invoke it again and i got the message: "You don't have permission to access this resource." I will experiment to see if this is a temporary problem.

Comment: I found a new source with a list of tools. https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/help/cosmology_calc.html  The first one is the one i used before which seems to be broken now. The 2nd 3rd and 4th seem to work OK.

Comment: The CosmoCalc tool I referenced at the end of my answer is now working again.

Comment: @kplt I have calculated the $\Omega_k$ value your question was asking for.

Comment: @kplt Now that I have finally corrected all my errors (I think) if anyone would like me to show any additional math for the equations I included, please let me know.

Comment: thanks for your feedback!